# Could not build module 'Foundation' in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have searched Stack Overflow, Google and fellow peers for a current workaround in Xcode 6 for this error but have failed in doing so.

**Note that this error occurs ONLY when attempting to run my app ON A DEVICE USING XCODE 6.**
(This is not an issue when using the simulators, and I can build my app on a device using Xcode 5)

It seems to be a framework or library issue, but since it is able to work in almost every other possible way, I am not sure where the solution resides. I was using Xcode 6.0.

Here is the error:

[image: error1]

[image: error]

I have checked my architecture settings, my frameworks and project files.  Everything that needs to be included seems to be there.
[image: arch]

This looks like it might be a silly error to do with Cocos2d and/or Xcode6.  I have used SpriteBuilder to create the app.  If you have a fix or have this error, any insight would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a fix. Downloaded the new Xcode6 version from the App Store.  **Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)** and it runs on all devices and simulators. 
(There was no notification to update Xcode, you must search for it and download the new version)

Comment: How does that make it a "temporary" fix? Do you plan on downgrading again sometime in the future? ;)
Also, in case of such issues, be sure to clean project and restart Xcode. Sometimes this can help change Xcode's mind.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, cleaning the project and restarting Xcode was not helping in this situation. Updating worked like a charm :)

Comment: I had this problem with Xcode 6.1 and just reinstalled Xcode 6.1 and it worked again. (facepalm)